# ftp_rawlist not running for huge directories

Tags: php, ftp

I am trying to get a list of files in the directory using ftp_rawlist(). The script is returning the file list with ftp_nlist(). But with ftp_rawlist() it doesn't returns anything. The directory which I am trying to get rawlist has 100k files.

Here is the code which I tried.

```
<?php 
 ini_set("memory_limit", "1024M");
 ini_set('max_execution_time', 0); //0=NOLIMIT
 set_time_limit(0);// no limit
 $conn_id = ftp_connect("xxxxx.xxx");
 $result = ftp_login($conn_id, "username", "password");
 ftp_pasv($conn_id, true);
 $ftpnlist = ftp_rawlist($conn_id, "/directory");
 var_dump($ftpnlist); //it throws false
 ?>
```

Comment: Is it possible that the directory path is incorrect? Can you do an ftp_pwd to see if you're in the place you expect to be upon initialization?

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I double checked it. ftp_nlist is working for that directory.

Comment: Are you sure that ftp_rawlist isn't disabled? Seen it on a few shared hosts.

Comment: @Ohgodwhy Yes, it is definitely not disabled because ftp_rawlist is returning file list for other directories but not for this one and secondly, I am on a AWS dedicated machine.

Comment: What version of PHP are you using?  I am seeing there are bugs in this function in older versions.

Comment: @JosephCrawford I am currently using php 5.5 version